# Storing large encrypted files on Heroku

Tags: facebook-graph-api, heroku, amazon-s3, storage

We have developed a Facebook application that runs on Heroku. The application generates encrypted text that needs to be stored quickly. Currently, the text is simply written to a text file on the Heroku server, and this is not a scalable solution.

The data will eventually be downloaded to our local machines, but it is essential to have a reliable intermediate storage between the app and the local machine due to the inability of downloading rapidly at our end.

Would you recommend S3 for this purpose? Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 to S3. This is because Heroku is a read only file system, so you probably have to source for some third party solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, i would recommend the s3. Very reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting S3 offers server side encryption. In fact, the aws-s3 SDK ruby gem has built in support for client side encryption as well.